# Ask Question problem

Tags: support, stack-overflow, user-accounts, post-ban

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What can I do when getting “Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-from-this)

Why can not ask a question on stackoverflow? When I try, I get this message: Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account.

Comment: Actually, might have something to do with the massive delete you've been doing.  I'd suggest you email team@stackoverflow.com.

Answer (score 3):

Here's you answer: [FaQ Entry](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-from-this). You seem to have tripped the threshold for poor quality questions/answers. For more information please see the above link.